# How do I implement a slice in a Python function?

Tags: python

```
def verify_card_number(card_number):
    sum_of_odd_digits = 0
    card_number_reversed = card_number[0:4:2:]
    print(card_number_reversed)
```

From the above code how do I solve this task?
" Reverse the order of the digits in the last four digits of `card_number`, by using a slice with a step of -1. You can use either negative or positive indices for the start and end indices. "

```
def verify_card_number(card_number):
    sum_of_odd_digits = 0
    card_number_reversed = card_number[-1:0:4:2:]
    print(card_number_reversed)
```

I tried placing the -1 there as shown but it returned false

Comment: What is `card_number`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)

Answer (score 1):

You need to slice the string in two parts - i.e., 1) up to but excluding the last 4 characters and 2) the last 4 characters.

You can then concatenate these two parts having reversed the last 4 characters.

Something like this:

```
def verify_card_number(card_number):
    return card_number[:-4] + card_number[-4:][::-1]
```

In case for some reason you don't want to use slicing then:

```
def verify_card_number_no_slice(card_number):
    cn = list(card_number)
    cn[-1], cn[-4] = cn[-4], cn[-1]
    cn[-2], cn[-3] = cn[-3], cn[-2]
    return "".join(cn)
```

You should verify that the card number being used has at least 4 characters